# Nodemailer - How to send OTP using Nodemailer in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, nodemailer

Hello Community I am stuck at one point. I want to develop on functionality in this functionality when we call email send route it will also send the OTP.

I am developed two functions one is for email send and one is for nodemailer.

**Email sent function**

```
const emailSend = async (req,res)=>{

let data = await users.findOne({email: req.body.email})

const responseType = {};

if(data){
    let otpCode = Math.floor((Math.random()*10000)+1);
    let otpData = new otp({
        email: req.body.email,
        code: otpCode,
        expiresIn: new Date().getTime() + 300*1000
    })

    let otpResponse = await otpData.save();
    responseType.statusText = 'Success'
    responseType.message = 'Please check your email id'

}
else{
    responseType.statusText = 'Error'
    responseType.message = 'Email id not exist'

}
res.status(200).json(responseType);
}
```

**Nodemailer function**

```
const mailer = () =>{
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    port: 587,
    secureConnection: false,
    auth: {
        user: 'Your Email',
        pass: 'Your Password'
    }
});

var mailOptions = {
    from: 'sender address',
    to: 'list of receivers',
    subject: 'Test',
    text: "Hello",
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    }
    console.log('Email Sent: '+ info);
});
}
```

When I hit email sent URL on Postman tool it will send the email but I want send email as well as OTP is also send.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const sendMail = async function (mailModel) {
    try {
        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: config.mailer.service,
            host: config.mailer.host,
            port: config.mailer.port,
            secure: config.mailer.secure,
            service: 'gmail',
            host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
            port: 465,
            secure: false,
            auth: {
                user: "email address",
                pass: 'password'

            },

        });

        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            let mailOptions = {
                from: mailModel.from || 'default email',
                to: mailModel.to,
                subject: mailModel.subject,
                html: mailModel.html
            };
            transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {

                mailOptions.err = err;
                mailOptions.info = info;
                mailOptions.status = (info !== null || info !== undefined);
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    reject(err);

                } else {
                    console.log(info);
                    resolve(info);
                }
            });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("email Error :", error);
        return Promise.reject(error)
    }

}

const genrateOTP = () => {
    // otp logic 
    return '123'
}
const otp = genrateOTP()

sendMail({
    to: 'ab.sd@gmail.com',
    subject: 'OTP',
    html: otp
})
```